# Handle Encryption in C# and Entity Framework

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on encrypted CC number column and some other columns and seeking for some help.

Here is the scenario: let's say I implemented encryption like this:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/

Now, my C# developers need to modify their code to ADD like below

Step #1:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY EncryptColumn 
    DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE CertificateforColumns
```

Step #2:

Any T-SQL `SELECT` or insert or update or delete

Step #3:

```
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY EncryptColumn;
```

Is there a shortcut like just `SELECT FUNCTION` or `EXEC SP_Function`, or something like that would make it easier for my developers, and to cut down on time spent modifying existing code?

Comment: Did you try writing a function which encrypts / decrypts the values?

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? In 2016 there is a new feature that allows for encryption and even querying encrypted data, you have to provide the encryption key in the SqlConnection and also specify that its enabled in the connection string. After that you do not have to write anything special as the encryption/decryption occurs database side. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163865.aspx. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt757097.aspx

Comment: I am using sql server 2014-Enterprise edition